# Can t update ssh

Tags: server, ssh

I have two server, the first (target) is running my website and can t be rebooted. The second is my backup server. I want backup to be able to rsync to target.

I can connect to the two with putty on windows, but when I try to ssh from backup to target, I get a timeout. (But target can ssh to backup...).

On backup server, I have:

```
backup$ssh -V
OpenSSH_6.1p1 Debian-4, OpenSSL 1.0.1c 10 May 2012
```

But on the targeted server:

```
target$ ssh -V
OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.2, OpenSSL 1.0.1 14 Mar 2012
```

I believe it s why I can t get backup to ssh to target. I tried to `apt-get update && apt-get install ssh` and `apt-get install openssh-server`, but the version keep being the same.

How can I update target's ssh server to be able to connect to it from backup?

EDIT:

Added the `ssh -vvv` if someone wonder:

```
backup$ ssh -vvv vod.121video.com
OpenSSH_6.1p1 Debian-4, OpenSSL 1.0.1c 10 May 2012
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to target [XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX] port 22.
debug1: connect to address XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX port 22: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host target port 22: Connection timed out
```

EDIT2:

With the config file of Sylvain's answer:

```
backup$ ssh -vvv target
OpenSSH_6.1p1 Debian-4, OpenSSL 1.0.1c 10 May 2012
debug1: Reading configuration data /root/.ssh/config
debug1: /root/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for target
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Executing proxy command: exec ssh proxyserver nc -q0 target 22
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug1: permanently_drop_suid: 0
debug3: Incorrect RSA1 identifier
debug3: Could not load "/root/.ssh/id_rsa" as a RSA1 public key
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: Checking blacklist file /usr/share/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: Checking blacklist file /etc/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
ssh: Could not resolve hostname proxyserver: No such file or directory
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

Comment: Once logged into backup, try first to `ping` your target server to see if it can be reachable.

Comment: Done, I get the ping back.

Answer (score 0):

As **target** is a production server, I'm not sure that you can ssh to it directly. May be you'll have to setup a ssh configuration to first connect to a proxy server, like this:

```
Host target
  ProxyCommand ssh proxyserver nc -q0 %h %p
  ForwardAgent yes
```

Comment: This seems to be a networking problem more than anything else and the above won't apply to Putty+Windows (which is what's being used)

Comment: @Sylvain I m trying it, just for information, what does it do?

Comment: @Oli: Putty work, what I m trying is to get backup to ssh to target, the two of them are ubuntu12.04 server.

Comment: @Sylvain: See edit

Comment: @DrakaSAN, It will try first to connect to your possible <proxyserver> and from there automatically ssh to target. proxyserver was just a generic name for an hypothetical third machine, sorry.

Comment: Wait a minute, from the last edit I can I see that you're ssh using your root account, probably not what you wanted.

Comment: Remove my config suggestion and try with a non-root user from your backup server.